# База данных городов, областей и стран СНГ

Tags: база-данных, геолокация, геокодирование

Ищу никак не могу найти нормальную базу. Что требуется

1. 3 страны (Россия, Украина, Белоруссия)
2. Города, только крупные города, или же поселки городского типа. Или чтобы можно было как-то в базе данных различить где что.
3. В формате SQL желательно.

Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто-то знает хорошие варианты. 
Спасибо

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это вопрос не по программированию.

Answer (score 2):

Вот есть большая база данных стран/областей/городов. [GitHub](https://github.com/Legostaev/contry_region_city)

**UPD:** Вот намного более крупная база. [GitHub](https://github.com/x88/i18nGeoNamesDB)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, видел данные базы, просто нужна такая где есть указание на то какого типа это поселок, то есть село, городского типа или город